# Can I listen to a WCF event from a web client?

Tags: wcf, events

Can I listen to a WCF event from a web client? Is this possible? I am not talking about call backs, I want the WCF service to raise and event and the web client to be able to listen. Is there a good example of this in C#?

Comment: So then, what is the difference between calling a WCF method asynchronously vs.  Duplex message exchange pattern?  I have read that WCF service can publish events which clients can then subscribe to. However , I am not sure if web clients could do this.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx#S5

Comment: Rowan,I have this exact question.  Did you ever figure out how to do this using WCF.  If so do you think you could answer your own question?

Answer (score 0):

There are no events in WCF. If you want mimic event you still have to call some operation exposed on all clients = you must call WCF service or callback exposed on client.

What do you mean by web client? Do you mean javascript code running in web browser? In such case no you can't achieve that with WCF. You can only use AJAX calls from borowser and continuously poll the service for possible "event".

If you mean ASP.NET application then the answer is theoretically yes, practiacally it will be pretty hard. The reason is that in ASP.NET you handle only current HTTP request by some handler - for example Page. The lifetime of the handler is only for serving the single request. Due to that using duplex service doesn't make to much sense because for receiving callbacks by duplex service your client proxy must live. If you open the proxy in Page it will die after serving the request. If you open the proxy in separate thread you must somehow corelate incomming callbacks to actual client but the client still have to poll the web server to be notified about callbacks. Similar situation will be with exposing the service on ASP.NET application.

Difference between asynchronnous and duplex calls is big. In asynchronnous pattern single request always have single response. Resonse is not sent without request. In duplex pattern you can make single request and receive thousands callback from server.